# $p$-norm of sum is less or equal to sum of $p$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Assume $f$ is nonnegative and measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{l+m}$, $p\geq1$.

PROVE the following inequality:
$$\left(\int_{\mathbb {R}^l}\left(\int_{\mathbb {R}^m}f(x,y)dy\right)^pdx\right)^{\frac {1}{p}}
\leq 
\int_{\mathbb {R}^m}\left(\int_{\mathbb {R}^l}f(x,y)^p dx\right)^{\frac {1}{p}}dy$$

Roughly, another way to say $p$-norm of sum is less or equal to sum of $p$-norm? However it's a bit confusing expressed by funcitons and integrals. I'm trying to begin with every norm is a convex function and then apply [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) but here is not a probablistic setting (surely there are more details missing thus a vain attempt).

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your are trying to prove that the $p-$ norm is a norm, right? Because that inequality is one of the conditions that any norm must satisfy.

Comment: @PierreCarre I’m trying to prove the inequality. I'll edit the question in case of misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, my point is just that in no moment you should use the fact that the $p-$ norm is a norm, because if you assume it's a norm, there os nothing to prove. With that said, just lookup any functional analysis book... When the $L^p$ spaces are defined you'll find what you seek.

Comment: @PierreCarre You mean simply by triangle inequality i.e. Minkowski inequality? But I cannot work out the above inequality based on integral. How can I convert addition to integral？ Things like infinite sum?

Comment: I forget the proof of this, but you seem to have a reasonable idea: if you replace $ f $ with a simple function (finitely many distinct values), then you can use Minkowski.  Then you might proceed by approximating $ f $ with simple functions from below.  Dominated convergence might finish the job.

Comment: Here is a great proof from my PhD advisor's lecture notes, using duality.  Page 14 of http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Harmonic%20Analysis2.pdf .

Comment: @JakeMirra Thanks. Well I suppose I need some functional analysis to understand the first equal.